# How to call product information?

Tags: magento

I am trying to get a static block to pull information. Using Magento 1.7 CE.

In the static box I am using the following code:

```
<div>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="6" template="catalog/product/listmenu.phtml"}}</div>
```

I want this to display the product name, price, and image... What do I list in the listmenu.phtml so it pulls the correct information?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the block type is "catalog/product_list", you can access the functionality of the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, i.e. a product collection loaded by the category id. So the approximate code outputting a list of products and their names, images, and prices would be:

```
<?php
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<div>
<h4><?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName());?></h4>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); 
?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php 
echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```